# Why can't you assign a dictionary in a map operation in JS like this?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object

Can someone explain to me my error in logic for why this doesn't work to assign a key value pair in javascript and initialize their values to 0? The values return as undefined.

What is the best way to do this instead?

Example:

```
const letters = ['i','c','l','e'];
let dict = {};

dict = letters.map(value => dict[value] = 0);
```

Comment: `map` is not intended to have side-effects. Use `for(of)` instead.

Comment: You can. But you immediately throw away the object by replacing `dict` with the array returned by `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map()` returns an array of the results of the callback. So you're replacing the object with that array.

Since you're modifying the object in the loop, you don't need to assign back to the variable. And since you don't need an array of the results, you should use `forEach()` rather than `map()`

```
letters.forEach(letter => dict[letter] = 0);
```

BTW, in JavaScript we call these *objects*, not *dictionaries*.